# How to solve net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED or net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

Current url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

When I trying to send request to `http://127.0.0.1:9000/`, it provides `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` or `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. But `http://127.0.0.1:9000/` works properly when I trying to call separately in browser. Other APIs are working properly. What is the reason for this? How can I solve this issue?

My Code:

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:9000')
     .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
```

`vue` 3.2.31

`axios` 0.25.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get a CORS Policy Error because we have these default headers in our bootstrap.js

`window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';`

You should remove default headers for one request in axios. You can use the `transformRequest` in the request you are making:

```
axios.get('xxxx.com', { transformRequest: [(data, headers) => {
   delete headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
   return data 
}] })
.then((response) => {
   console.log(response);
})
```

Comment: Could you please post your resources link as well?

Answer (score -1):

The project ip is different from axios request ip cause by CROS policy Error , you can solve by changing `devServer` config in `vue.config.js` to add configuration item `host:0.0.0.0` or `host:127.0.0.1`